# How do i use a Word.RangeCollection in different contexts?

Tags: javascript, promise, ms-word, office365, office-js

Lets say i search for a word and track the returned Word.RangeCollection , how do i use those ranges in another Word.run context? Ive searched around and tried many different things to get this to work , closest ive gotten was with the following

```
var searchResults;

function search(term){//this works as expected
    Word.run(function (context) {
        searchResults = context.document.body.search(term, { ignorePunct: true });
        searchResults.track();

        context.load(searchResults, ["font"]);

        return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
                searchResults.items[i].font.highlightColor = "#FFFF00";
            }
        })
        .then(context.sync);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}

function clearSearch(){
    Word.run(searchResults, (context) => {//pass in Word.RangeCollection so its .context can be reused
        searchResults.load("font");
        return context.sync()
        .then(function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {//!!!Cant access items here
                searchResults.items[i].font.highlightColor = null;
            }
            //searchResults.untrack();
        })
        .then(context.sync);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}
```

running search("anywordinmydoc") works fine, but running clearSearch() after tells me i need to load the property items. As i understand it calling .load("font") on a RangeCollection should load the font property of all the Range objects in the items[] so searchResults.items should be loaded and accessible.

I cant seem to load searchResults.items, not sure what im doing wrong but i need to be able to keep track of and use a Word.RangeCollection in multiple functions.

Comment: `Word.run()` returns Promise, which can itself be returned from `search()`. It shouldn't be too difficult to make that Promise resolve to `searchResults`, thereby making the two function calls chainable (via .then) with `searchResults` passed to `clearSearch()`.